# Listing all files in a folder from an Azure pipeline

Tags: cmd, azure-pipelines, cicd

I am trying to execute a command for every file inside the build directory by doing something that looks like this:

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'List files'
  inputs:
    script: |
      for %f in ( "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\*" ) do @echo %f
```

I am getting the following error though,

```
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Script contents:
for %f in ( "C:\Users\tester\my_agent\_work\1\a\*" ) do @echo %f
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "C:\Users\tester\my_agent\_work\_temp\7a83c3a7-8a9e-4edf-aa36-e4e14d1ee5c7.cmd""
\Users\tester\my_agent\_work\1\a\*" ) do @echo f was unexpected at this time.
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '255'.
Finishing: List files
```

How can I correct my task above so it works as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a batch script you have to **double the %**:

Here is the example:

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'List files'
  inputs:
    script: |
      for %%f in ( "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\*" ) do @echo %%f
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```yaml
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'List files'
  inputs:
    script: |
      dir /a-D /S /B
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

Comment: I want to execute a command for every file in the list so I tried altering your suggestion to `for /F %A in ('dir "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\*" /s /b') do @echo %~dpnxA`
Only to get:
**The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~dpnxA** 
and if I replace `%~dpnxA` with `%A` I get `##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '255'.`